# My pc dosen't turn off since Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, bug-reporting

Since I installed Ubuntu 14.10 my pc does shut down, **but 3 seconds later it's turning on again.**

My current work-around is to visit the BIOS and press F10 and Enter and restart, and then turn it off.

I've looked around a bit but nothing works.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: What does this 3 seconds off mean? *"well it does, but 3 seconds after it's turning on againg"*. Does it completely power off, no fans or lights or anything?

Answer (score 0):

That honestly sounds like a hardware issue, do you have a dualboot config set up, or a prior edition of Ubuntu to load and test?

Comment: But it was working before upgrading to 14.10 -> probably software. Double-checking with an old Ubuntu live iso could confirm

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to enter BIOS setup and look for the Power Management settings? Maybe there are some settings starting with "Wake-on-...", which you could try to disable. I think that possibly a device (keyboard, mouse, lan, usb, ...) is waking the machine up for any reason. If you think you know what I'm talking about, try disabling one of those enabled "Wake-on-?" options, reboot, shut down and see if it stays off. If not, re-enable the option and try the next until you possibly find the cause. Please do NOT change anything else in BIOS if you don't know what you do, as this could prevent your pc from booting! Greetings and good luck.